# View Virtualbox Website On Mobile Over Wi-Fi Network

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have established a pretty solid virtualbox local development environment with my host runnng Debian 11 and my Guest running Ubuntu 20.04 server, Virtualmin 7, and LAMP.  My Guest gets internet access via a virtualbox host-only adapter. (no dhcp) and I am running DNSmasq as well.

I often work on multiple different public wifi networks (not just home)...

My question is...

Is it even somehow possible to figure my Guest's ip address to be visible over any network that both my phone and my Host are connected to? If possible, I would appreciate a good set of instructions.

**Additional Info:**
Almost forgot...  I ALWAYS connect my mobile to whatever WI-FI network... then connect my laptop to my mobile's "hotspot" wifi.
thx

Comment: You might need to abandon the host-only adapter.

Comment: You would need to switch to Bridged Networking to access it from anywhere.

Comment: Tech mandate for the host-only adapter.. Vmin in Vbox..

Comment: That does not mean it will work from anywhere. Maintain use in your Home Network.

Comment: Seems like an awesome solution to this would be a "developer's phone app"..... any high level developers run across this... run with it... Happy to beta test for ya... :-)